# Creating a .bat file to connect a dial up connection

Tags: batch-file, command, dial-up

I am using windows 8.1 and I am facing some serious annoying problem.

My ISP gives me a username and password to connect through a dial up broadband connection.

But every time I got disconnected I need to reconnect using the password and username again and again which is very very long and annoying. So I am looking for a command line code which I can make a .bat file and which will run the dial up connection with the username and password set in it every time I click on the .bat file..

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create connect.txt and paste these codes with your connection_name user_name password

```
rasdial Connection User password
```

now rename connect.txt to connect.bat and paste it to start up.. (run-> `shell:startup`)

Hope this helps.